# How to set record id by myself in J2ME

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I use `RecordStore` to store my data.

I know when we store data in `RecordStore`, it automatically generates a record id for each record.

But how can I **set** the record id by myself? Or how can I **get** the record id?

Because I want to use the `recordstore.setRecord(..)` method to update my recordstore.

But when I use `RecordEnumeration` to fetch `RecordStore` and use method `nextRecordId()`, it just shows odd or even ids. I mean when I have 8 records, it just prints out only odd or even records like

> 2 4 6 8

My code:

```
    handleRecord.openRecordStore(handleRecord.getRecordName());
    RecordEnumeration re;
    try {
         int rc = handleRecord.getRecordStore().getNumRecords();
         re = hrs.getRcs().enumerateRecords(null, null, true);

         while(re.hasNextElement()) {
             int rid = re.nextRecordId();
             System.out.println(rid);
         }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: from what you describe it appears like you have a simple error in loop - hopping over records. Please show the code you use to iterate `RecordEnumeration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIDP API doesn't have method to set record id by yourself.

See [RecordStore API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html) for explanation how this is supposed to work.

- *"Records are uniquely identified within a given record store by their recordId, which is an integer value. This recordId is used as the primary key for the records. The first record created in a record store will have recordId equal to one (1). Each subsequent record added to a RecordStore will be assigned a recordId one greater than the record added before it. That is, if two records are added to a record store, and the first has a recordId of 'n', the next will have a recordId of 'n + 1'..."*

The code that iterates the store appears OK:

```
     re = hrs.getRcs().enumerateRecords(null, null, true);
     while(re.hasNextElement()) {
         int rid = re.nextRecordId();
         System.out.println(rid);
     }
```

if you're getting *only odd or even record* like 2-4-6... or 1-3-5... printed as a result, first thing to check is whether you somehow removed records that are "missing" - this could be done eg using `RecordStore.getVersion` method:

- *"Each time a record store is modified (by addRecord, setRecord, or deleteRecord methods) its version is incremented. This can be used by MIDlets to quickly tell if anything has been modified..."*